# How do I migrate from Google login to Launchpad login?

Tags: support, launchpad

I have tried logging in with my Launchpad ID. But it shows me as a totally new user, with rep of 0.

I don't want to lose the rep I have here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

Go to [your profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/65492/daniel-clem) and near the top there will be a link that says *My logins*.

[image]

It will show you all the accounts associated with you Stack Exchange account, and let you add new ones and remove old ones.

[image]

Here you can add your Launchpad account and remove your Google account.

Moderators can also do this, and one might beat you to it :)

Comment: Sometimes, there's a Meta answer that deserves Rep... this is one of them. Easy to understand, with screenshots.

Comment: Thank you! It had been a long while since I'd been on here, so I didn't know you had submitted an answer @Seth. I'll try this now, if I don't comment again saying it worked, then I had problems lol

Comment: Seems to have worked @Seth, Thank you very much for the clear and specific answer. If I have issues later I'll try to remember this thread here and try and come back.

Comment: Thanks a TON @Seth! I was going to ask a question very similar to this (Launchpad & Wordpress) because I log on to raspberrypi.stackexchange.com with my Wordpress ID and thought it would be easier if I logged into one and got into the other, but I didn't want to lose my Reputatin. I noticed this question and your answer is incredibly informative and worked like a charm! I also got 100 Rep from it all! Thanks!