# How do I connect all my accounts to my StackExchange account?

Tags: support

I have a main Stack Exchange account.

Firstly, I want to delete the other Ask accounts I've made on other services, (like Google, for example) if possible.

Then I want to merge all my accounts, for example my Google account.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: My answer here should help you with this: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6093/how-do-i-migrate-from-google-login-to-launchpad-login/6094#6094

Comment: but my google account has an account. how can i close it then link it?

Comment: Oh you mean you have two SE accounts with two different OpenIDs?