# how to acces my profile on Ask Ubuntu if I've forgotten my OpenID?

Tags: support, login

Probably it's not the right place to ask this question, but maybe at least somebody would help me where should I ask it.

When I was creating my profile on askubuntu.com I've chosen the option of logging with myOpenID. I didn't have it already, so I've created one that time, on askubuntu login page. I'm permanently logged in on askubuntu.com - but I've forgotten my OpenID and I can't acces the site form any other computer... How can I retrive it or choose an other way to logg in, but conserving my user name and profile?

Comment: You probably want to take a look at http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6093/how-do-i-migrate-from-google-login-to-launchpad-login/6094#6094

Comment: thanks a lot :)